# linux library problem

Tags: linux, gcc

Everybody out there,
I'm writing a c code which have a strange problem when I compile it .
The source code is OK.
I compile it with following option:

```
$ gcc above_sample.c -I/home/hadoop/project/hadoop-0.20.2/src/c++/libhdfs -L/home/hadoop/project/hadoop-0.20.2/c++/Linux-amd64-64/lib -lhdfs  -o above_sample.
```

But it show the out put like that:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libjvm.so, needed by /home/hadoop/project/hadoop-0.20.2/c++/Linux-amd64-64/lib/libhdfs.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link) /home/hadoop/project/hadoop-0.20.2/c++/Linux-amd64-64/lib/libhdfs.so: undefined reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM@SUNWprivate_1.1' 
/home/hadoop/project/hadoop-0.20.2/c++/Linux-amd64-64/lib/libhdfs.so: undefined reference to `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs@SUNWprivate_1.1'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I searched for libjvm.so i found It in my system in /usr/java/lib.

I made a symbolic link of it but did not work.

i copied the library in to several places like usr/lib check the LD_library_Path
but could not manage to compile the program it showing the same error again and again

Can any one tell me what I'm doing  wrong ? 
how to link .so file  to gcc ?
or how .so files are linked in program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding:

```
-L/usr/java/lib
```

To your linker command, since that's the library your linker is not being able to find: `I_GetCreatedJavaVMs@SUNWprivate_1.1`.

A little piece of advice: it's not a good idea to mess with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Just fix your linker command.

Comment: My code is having the same error as described by the OP. The system found libjvm.so in multiple locations. However, the solution by "adding -LLOCATION_to_libjvm.so" does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 2):

Linker gives a warning about not found reference to function JNI_CreateJavaVM@SUNWprivate_1.1

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: libhdfs.so: undefined reference to
>   `JNI_CreateJavaVM@SUNWprivate_1.1'

This function name might be specific for library from Sun/Oracle HotSpot JVM. Other JVMs may have another name. For example, mine OpenJDK had only shorter name such as JNI_CreateJavaVM and linker gave me the same warning.

You may get list of the functions from your **libjvm.so** by running command:

```
readelf -s libjvm.so | grep JNI_CreateJavaVM # given that you are in catalog containing libjvm.so
```

If output does not contain required function, then you might want to install another JDK.

Answer (score 0):

That's what worked for me:

```
CDH=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH
OS_ARCH=amd64

gcc hdfs_example.c -I$CDH/include -L$CDH/lib64 \
       -L/usr/java/default/jre/lib/${OS_ARCH}/server \
       -ljvm -lhdfs -o hdfs_write_test
```