# Linux library linking issue - HADOOP HDFS C API

Tags: linux, gcc, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to run the hdfs_test application that comes alongside the C API library. When I'm compiling the application using the command:

```
gcc myTest.c -I/usr/HDFS/src/c++/libhdfs -L/usr/HDFS/build/c++/Linux-i386-32/lib -lhdfs -o myTest
```

I do that after setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/i386/libjava.so
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/HDFS/build/c++/Linux-i386-32/lib/libhdfs.so: undefined reference to `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs'
/usr/HDFS/build/c++/Linux-i386-32/lib/libhdfs.so: undefined reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I saw this post:
[linux library problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790085/linux-library-problem), 
and I thought it might be relevant, even though I'm not getting a "library not found" warning.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe a `-ljava` is missing in your compilation command.

Comment: I tried the -ljava but I started instead the previous error getting:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljava

Comment: You miss a `-L/some/dir/containing/libjava/` argument (for a directory containing `libjava.so*`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with both libhdfs and libjvm!

I guess the best way to help is to show you a working setup. Here is my 'LIBS' in my Makefile:

```
LIBS=-L/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/usr/lib/ -lhdfs -L/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/jre/lib/amd64/server/ -ljvm -Wl,-rpath=/usr/hdp/2.6.4.091/usr/lib/:/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/jre/lib/amd64/server/
```

You want to use "-Wl,-rpath" so you don't need to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH. And here is the ldd result after linking. You want to make sure all libraries are resolved:

```
[my-prompt]$ ldd myprogram
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcf7048000)
    libhdfs.so.0.0.0 => /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/usr/lib/libhdfs.so.0.0.0 (0x00007fd120723000)
    libjvm.so => /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so (0x00007fd11f730000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000390be00000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000000390c600000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000000390ca00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000390ba00000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x000000390c200000)
```

When you run it, since it eventually runs Java byte code, you also need to set CLASSPATH. Here is what you can do:

```
export CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath --glob`
./your-program
```

It's a late answer, but I hope it can save other people some trouble.